# Easy Custom Labelling and CRS Issues

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling

I'm having several issues with a vector layer in a project I have been working on for the last week. None of the overall settings have been changed but it appears that there is an issue with the CRS and the label leader lines within Easy Labelling.

I have a layer called 'events', and when I try to insert it, it will only display in the right place if I use CRS WS84 as opposed to OSBG1936 even though all the other layers and the project are set to the latter CRS. I only found this out because my label layer disappeared when I opened the project earlier, even though it was fine yesterday.

Now when I try to label 'events' it's clear that the nodes are not in the right place and the leader lines refuse to display, and quite frankly, I am totally confused!

I have tried: (1) a fresh set of data, (2) a new project and changing the CRS for the events layer (but that just puts them all in the wrong place).

The labelling for all the other layers is fine, so I can't understand how this layer has become corrupt.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you also install the **Memory layer saver** plugin? The description of the [_EasyCustomLabeling_](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/) layer mentions this requirement if you want to restore the labels correctly.

Comment: Hi Joseph, yes I have that plugin installed :)

Comment: could you maybe post the content of the .prj-file of your events layer? The hole thing really sounds strange...

Comment: Happy to - how do I get to the content? Through QGIS?